# "StdIn.isEmpty()" java:

Tags: java, stdin

"StdIn.isEmpty()" java: I am using eclipse, the console never shows output, because I can't figure out how can I terminate giving inputs. I tried pressing space/tab/enter, but the console still doesn't show the output and keeps on demanding more input.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Am I correct in saying you're following a course on coursera about algorithms? `StdIn` is one of the classes in the library provided by the lecture.

If it is this class, you should say so in your post and provide a link to the implementation.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.html

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are passing a text file...if so, please use

```
java foo < bar.txt
```

instead of

```
java foo bar.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that the console keeps demanding the input from the user, and never terminates. This can be resolved by simply pressing 'Control + d'.

This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could press ctrl-z (at least in Windows this works for me) but you probably don't want to do that. This would mean your program could only ever read once from the console. Better would be that you only read a line at a time rather than try to read "the whole file". Then you can just press enter to finish reading. Somthing like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String t = s.nextLine();
```